# Allow node author to assign edit rights for other users

Tags: entities, users

Use case: user X creates a node and wants to give user Y the ability to edit the node as well. Think page administrators on Facebook. An [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field can be used to allow the node author to associate other users with the node, but how to provide edit rights for selected users?

A simple and common use case is a business directory website where Employee X creates a listing for Company Y and wants to allow Employee Z to edit the listing as well. There are several similar solutions out there but I've not been able to find a specific module or recipe for this common use case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As is usually the case, "there's a "module for that": [Node access user reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) meets the requirements for this use case by allowing node authors to select other users from a [user reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) or [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field and assign view, update or delete rights to the referenced users. Hope this is useful for anyone else who runs into this issue.